# CreateWellKnownSid says Parameter is incorrect with WinAccountAdministratorSid, but works with WinBuiltAdministratorsSid

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the well known SID for the builtin administrator account using `CreateWellKnownSid` so I can use it in other functions, but I am getting **The parameter is incorrect** error message when using `WinAccountAdministratorSid` as first parameter; however, if I use `WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid` or `WinBuiltinUsersSid` it works. No idea what's going on.

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <LM.h>
#include <locale.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")

#define MAX_NAME 256

VOID ShowError(DWORD errorCode)
{
    //FormatMessageW
    DWORD flags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;
    LPWSTR errorMessage;
    DWORD size = 0;

    if (!FormatMessageW(flags, NULL, errorCode, 0, (LPWSTR)&errorMessage, size, NULL))
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Could not get the format message, error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    wprintf(L"\n%s", errorMessage);

    LocalFree(errorMessage);
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
{
    _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"English");

    //LocalAlloc
    UINT memFlags = LMEM_FIXED; //Allocates fixed memory
    DWORD numOfBytes = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
    PSID builtInAdminSid;

    /*Allocating memory to hold the SID for the
    built-in administrator user*/
    if (!(builtInAdminSid = LocalAlloc(memFlags, numOfBytes)))
    {
        ShowError(GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //CreateWellKnownSid
    WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE accountAdminSid = WinAccountAdministratorSid;
    PSID domainSid = NULL;

    /*We will ask Windows for the well known Admin SID.
    If this function fails, we cannot continue*/
    if (!CreateWellKnownSid(accountAdminSid, NULL,
                            builtInAdminSid, &numOfBytes))
    {
        ShowError(GetLastError());
        LocalFree(builtInAdminSid); //Do not forget to free memory!
        return 1;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Seems like I have to specify the `DomainSid` parameter, but how do I retrieve it for the local computer?

Comment: What is your OS? It seems as if on Windows 7 about 3 dozen of the enums are not working.

Comment: @WernerHenze, thanks for answering. I tried on Windows 7 and Windows 10, same result.

Comment: It looks like `DomainSid` [is not optional for some well known SIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5045607/7571258).

Comment: You could also directly use DOMAIN_USER_RID_ADMIN (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Can you tell me how to specify the `DomainSid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some time `CreateWellKnownSid` require *DomainSid* parameter by very simply reason - it concatenation the *DomainSid* with well known rid (add one SubAuthority to sid).

for get *DomainSid* we can use [`LsaQueryInformationPolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378313(v=vs.85).aspx) with *PolicyAccountDomainInformation* - *Retrieves the name and SID of the system's account domain.* - this api call return [`POLICY_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721895(v=vs.85).aspx) structure where exist *DomainSid*

```
#include <Ntsecapi.h>

ULONG CreateSid()
{
    LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle;

    static LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa) };

    NTSTATUS status = LsaOpenPolicy(0, &oa, POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &PolicyHandle);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PPOLICY_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_INFO ppadi;

        if (0 <= (status = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle, PolicyAccountDomainInformation, (void**)&ppadi)))
        {
            PSID sid = alloca(MAX_SID_SIZE);

            ULONG cbSid = MAX_SID_SIZE;

            if (!CreateWellKnownSid(::WinAccountAdministratorSid, ppadi->DomainSid, sid, &cbSid))
            {
                status = GetLastError();
            }

            LsaFreeMemory(ppadi);
        }

        LsaClose(PolicyHandle);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: usually you got *S-1-5-21-x-y-z* for domain sid and *S-1-5-21-x-y-z-500* for *WinAccountAdministratorSid* where `500` is `DOMAIN_USER_RID_ADMIN`.  also we can use `ULONG cbSid = GetLengthSid(ppadi->DomainSid) + sizeof(DWORD);` instead `MAX_SID_SIZE` in this case

Comment: I am trying to test that, but cannot get `STATUS_SUCCESS` code to be recognized by Visual Studio, any idea why?

Comment: @SergioCalderon because it defined in *ntstatus.h* and you not include this files. and main *recognized by Visual Studio* - visual studio is shell - it nothing recognized at all. this is *CL.EXE* (compiler) say you about undefined symbol

Comment: @SergioCalderon - however - anyway `STATUS_SUCCESS` this is 0. Lsa api return error code. if no error, return 0

Comment: however i re-look - if you do - `#include <Ntsecapi.h>` - `#ifndef _NTDEF_
typedef _Return_type_success_(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS, *PNTSTATUS;
#endif` exist - are you include `Ntsecapi.h` ?

Comment: I did. I was able to get the `STATUS_SUCCESS` by adding `<Ntstatus.h>`, no idea why It was not documented. I am going to try and will be back to this thread. Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: @SergioCalderon - are you `#include <Ntsecapi.h>` ? in `Ntsecapi.h` alo declared `#ifndef _NTDEF_ typedef _Return_type_success_(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS, *PNTSTATUS; #endif`

Comment: Yes, I was including `#include <NTSecAPI.h>`, but `STATUS_SUCCESS` was **undefined**. Using `Ntstatus.h` works, but I am getting some warnings.

Comment: @SergioCalderon - yes, i confuse `NTSTATUS` definition with `STATUS_SUCCESS` which is really declared in *Ntstatus.h* only. however you can use `LSA_SUCCESS(Error)` macro instead too (look in *NTSecAPI.h*) . *but I am getting some warnings* - macro redefinition `C4005` i think. you can simply disable it before include *ntstatus.h* and re-enable (or pop to previous level) after

Answer (score 1):

For those who wonder how I set the RbMm's answer to my code, here it is:

```
// LsaOpenPolicy
    NTSTATUS nOpenPolicy;
    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    LSA_HANDLE policyHandle;

    // Fills a block of memory with zeros.
    ZeroMemory(&objectAttributes, sizeof(objectAttributes));

    nOpenPolicy = LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &objectAttributes,
                            POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &policyHandle);

    if (nOpenPolicy != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        ShowError(LsaNtStatusToWinError(nOpenPolicy));
        LocalFree(builtInAdminSid);
        return 1;
    }

    // LsaQueryInformationPolicy
    NTSTATUS nQueryInfo;
    POLICY_INFORMATION_CLASS policyInformation = PolicyAccountDomainInformation;
    PPOLICY_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_INFO pDomainInfo;

    nQueryInfo = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(policyHandle, policyInformation, (PVOID *)&pDomainInfo);

    if (nQueryInfo != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        ShowError(LsaNtStatusToWinError(nQueryInfo));
        LocalFree(builtInAdminSid);
        LsaClose(policyHandle);
        return 1;
    }   

    // CreateWellKnownSid
    WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE accountAdminSid = WinAccountAdministratorSid;


    /*  We will ask Windows for the well known Admin SID.
    If this function fails, we cannot continue  */
    if (!CreateWellKnownSid(accountAdminSid, pDomainInfo->DomainSid,
                            builtInAdminSid, &numOfBytes))
    {
        ShowError(GetLastError());
        LocalFree(builtInAdminSid); // Do not forget to free memory!
        LsaClose(policyHandle);
        return 1;

    }

    LsaClose(policyHandle);
    LsaFreeMemory(pDomainInfo);
```